# Read IMG file from DB using Flask and render it to HTML

Tags: sqlite, flask

I am trying to build a very simple Flask app that'll store image and user info. I'll be taking the upload from user using HTML upload input element and will save it to DB.
Found a tutorial to save the file into SQLite3 from flask but I'm not able to read the image and render it to User HTML image using IMG HTML tag.

Here is the code used to upload the image to DB,

```
class Img(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    img = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    mimetype = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)

def upload():
    pic = request.files['pic']
    if not pic:
        return 'No pic uploaded!', 400

    filename = secure_filename(pic.filename)
    mimetype = pic.mimetype
    if not filename or not mimetype:
        return 'Bad upload!', 400

    img = Img(img=pic.read(), name=filename, mimetype=mimetype)
    db.session.add(img)
    db.session.commit()

    return 'Img Uploaded!', 200
```

And when I do this,

```
Response(img.img, mimetype=img.mimetype)
```

The image gets opened but couldn't find how to send it to HTML IMG Tag

Now in Index.html, I want to add the uploaded IMG

```
<img src="{{imageURL}}/>"
```

Also is this way of storing images good?

Answer (score 1):

Since the image data is in binary form, I recommend using the [LargeBinary](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.LargeBinary) type to store the data in the database.
You can create your own endpoint to read and display the image. In this, the data is extracted from the database and delivered using the [`send_file`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.send_file) function. Depending on your needs, you can identify your image by the id column, as in the example below, or by the filename.

###### Flask (app.py)

```
from flask import (
    Flask,
    abort,
    render_template,
    request,
    send_file
)
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from io import BytesIO
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif'}

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Image(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    data = db.Column(db.LargeBinary, nullable=False)
    mime = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

with app.app_context():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            abort(400, description='No file part.')

        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            abort(400, description='No selected file.')

        if not allowed_file(file.filename):
            abort(400, description='Invalid image.')

        img = Image(
            name=secure_filename(file.filename),
            mime=file.mimetype,
            data=file.read()
        )
        db.session.add(img)
        db.session.commit()
    images = Image.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', **locals())

@app.route('/download/<int:image_id>')
def download(image_id):
    img = Image.query.get_or_404(image_id)
    return send_file(
        BytesIO(img.data),
        mimetype=img.mime,
        download_name=img.name
    )
```

###### HTML (templates/index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>

    <div id="images">
      {% for img in images -%}
      <img src="{{ url_for('download', image_id=img.id) }}" />
      {% endfor -%}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```